# Getting 404 when call request by haproxy (directly works fine)

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy

I directly call a web service with url 
 `curl http://venesh.ir/webservice/oauth/token`
and I got error 403,
but when I call it by reverse proxy from some server I got 404,is it possible that haproxy change my address?

haproxy config:

```
frontend localhost
    bind *:8081
    option tcplog
    mode tcp
    acl isVenesh dst_port 8081
    use_backend venesh if isVenesh
    default_backend venesh


backend venesh
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    server web01 venesh.ir:80 check
```

when I call `mySerevrIp:8081/webservice/oauth/token` I expect getting the result that I directly call 
`curl http://venesh.ir/webservice/oauth/token` that is 403,

but when I call `curl mySerevrIp:8081/webservice/oauth/token` I get error 404,

Is a problem with my haproxy or my config or is it possible that this problem is because of venesh.ir website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `http://venesh.ir/webservice/oauth/token` expects the host header to be `venesh.ir`.  You can test this from the command line.  If the host header is not `venesh.ir`, it will return 404:

```sh
$ curl -I -H 'Host: 1.1.1.1'  http://venesh.ir/webservice/oauth/token
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 24 Jun 2019 17:48:56 GMT
Server: Apache/2
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

You can add the host header to your configuration if you change your mode to http:

```
frontend localhost
    bind *:8081
    option httplog
    mode http
    default_backend venesh

backend venesh
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    http-request set-header Host venesh.ir
    server web01 venesh.ir:80 check
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @mweiss was true, and an alternative way that I found is Setting `HOST` value to `venesh.ir` in my request header then the tcp reverse proxy works fine.